# DB2 ODBC Connection thru Excel VBA

Tags: excel, db2, odbc, db2-luw

I am trying to connect to DB2 on AIX through excel VBA, my connection string is

> conn.ConnectionString = "Driver={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};Database=XXXXXXXX;Hostname=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;Port=50000;Protocol=TCPIP;Uid=username;Pwd=password;"

When I try to open  "conn.Open" the connection my windows logon credentials are used for authentication and not the one given in connection string.

Can you please help in resolving this.

Thanks In Advance. Gokul

Comment: EDIT your question to show the Db2 client configuration and version+fixpack.   If you make a DSN and configure it, does it work correctly with odbcad32 for connecting with your AIX-credentials?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add parameter Persist Security Info=False;to ConnectionString.